# Android canvas game loop breaks onResume() after closing and reopening app

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview, game-loop

On a fresh install, the first time I open the app, I don't really have any problems. However, If I were to kill the app via processes, force stop, or simply press the home button and re launch the app, I run into a few problems...

**First problem** - when the app is relaunched after closed or killed, there is a long delay before actually launching the app window. Also, sometimes it takes up to 30 seconds for the game graphics (whats being drawn to the canvas) to display. All I will see is a black screen while I hear the game sound effects playing in the background, as if it were running.

**Second problem** - After waiting about 30 seconds for the app to actually display the canvas, sometimes the on touch listener gets unregistered or something. I'm unable to interact with the game as if my touches were not registering. Once again, this only happens on a RELAUNCH after the app has successfully ran once and then closed / killed.

**Third problem** - in the case that I get impatient and do not wait the 30 seconds for the canvas to display, but instead tap the home button or kill the "unresponsive" app, I always get an error message saying something like "app unresponsive, wait? force close?" or "Unexpected error, App has stop running."

So these problems have led me to believe it is an issue with how I am starting / restarting / creating my game loop:

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{


MenuView menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    menu = new MenuView(this);
    menu.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    Button buttonplay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchCanvas();
        }
    });
}

public void launchCanvas(){
     setContentView(menu)
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         ////do stuff
    }
    return true;
}


////////////////////////////////////////inner MenuView class

public class MenuView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean ok;
    Game game;

    public MenuView(Context context){
        super(context);
        game = new Game(this);
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(ok){
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }

            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            onDraw(c);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 1, 5, 29);
        game.draw(canvas);
    }

    public void pause(){
        ok = false;
        while(true){
            try{
                t.join();
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t=null;
    }
    public void resume(){
        ok = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }



    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////end MenuView class`



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    menu.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    menu.resume();
}
```

}

Any ideas on how to fix?

**UPDATE - Potential Problem Discovered**
I believe the root of my problems came from not letting my thread sleep. I added the following try block in the draw() method that is called every iteration of the thread loop:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Although it is a bit choppy and uneven now, I have not been able to reproduce the problems described above.

I just changed from 10ms to sleep only 1ms, and It isn't choppy anymore AND still cannot reproduce the problems. 1ms seems kind of trivial... why is this necessary for the thread to sleep an insignificant amount of time?

Comment: Well thread sleeping saves the battery and gives the processor some rest... apart from that I can't really think of anything...

Comment: I've been trawling through the internet a while now, and this `sleep(1)` solution is all that has worked. I guess the important thing is it works, but it feels very hacky and I'm unsettled by not knowing why it works and how reliably it may work. I know this is an old question, but if anyone comes around to clarify, please @ me when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own SurfaceView-based app has a separate Thread in which two methods run: update() and draw(). However, the draw() method only runs if `canvas != null`. This is all the code I have related to pausing and resuming, apart from having a `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh) {...}`, which runs this code:

```
if(!thread.isAlive()) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

If this doesn't help you, relevant parts from my entire framework:

**Main.java**:

sets MainView as the content view (`setContentView(mainView)`)

**MainView.java**:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface created");
    tf = Typeface.create("Roboto", Typeface.BOLD);
    recalc=true;
    if(!thread.isAlive()) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

**MainThread.java**:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {
    // (abridged) Game logic loop
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
            // in the surface
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // update game state
                    mainView.update();
                    // render state to the screen
                    if (canvas != null) mainView.render(canvas); // canvas == null when activity is in background.
                    // ... my code then handles sleeping, etc. for fixed fps.
                }
            } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense to you! You should be able to adapt it to your own project as necessary.

Comment: I added a surfaceDestroyed and surfaceCreated override. Still have loading time problems, and still have the problem of the onTouchListener not working

Comment: When my touches don't register it says "Event dropped because it is stale" over and over again on the logcat

Comment: I think I found my problem.. updated the question. Would appreciate any further feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that a SurfaceView has two parts, a Surface and a View.  If you override `onDraw()` in a SurfaceView sub-class, you're going to do both, and whatever you draw on the View is going to obscure what you're drawing on the Surface.  (The Surface is an independent layer that, by default, sits behind the View UI layer.)

I generally recommend against sub-classing SurfaceView, as there is no value in doing so, and it creates the potential for weirdness.  A SurfaceView Surface is a thing you draw on, not an object whose behavior you need to specialize.  (Contrast with a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).)

You may want to read about [SurfaceView and Activity lifecycle interaction](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) for the pause/resume/thread logic, and [game loops](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops) for some ideas about how best to structure game rendering.  These point to [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for concrete examples.

Adding a sleep call will affect race conditions. Sleeping is not necessary if your app doesn't have a race.  (And, as argued in the game loop article, they're not a great way to manage your frame rate.)

Minor point: `ok` should be marked `volatile`, or the compiler is allowed to ignore it in `run()`.